# Compound possessives and yours

Tags: possessives

which is correct:

Thank you for your and your team's time

or

Thank you for yours and your team's time

and should (or does it make a difference if) I place commas before and after "and your team's"  ... thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

> Thank you for your and your team's time.

is the correct form of the two. In this case, *your* and *your team's* both modify *time*, which implies you are thanking the recipient for time that belonged to the recipient and to the team. 
If you received time from the team and, separately, from the recipient, you can acknowledge this by writing it as:

> Thank you for your team's time and for yours.

Answer (score 0):

The first variant is the correct one: "Thank you for your and your team's time."  If you split the sentence into two, it works:  "Thank you for your time.  Thank you for your team's time."

For the second variant proposed: "Thank you for yours and your team's time.", if you split it into two, the sentence "Thank you for yours time." doesn't work.

Comment: "Thank you for your time" does work. I don't see the point of your final sentence.

Comment: Yes, I should have been clearer.  I've edited my answer.  To be clear, "Thank you for your time" does work!  It's "Thank you for yours time" (with an 's') that does not.

Answer (score 0):

"your" is a possessive adjective before a noun, "yours" is a possessive pronoun, not used before a noun.

Typical exaamples for "yours"

- my father and yours (yours stands for "your father")
- that silly friend of yours
- This is my hat. Where is yours?

[Cambridge Grammar](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/grammatik/britisch-grammatik/pronouns-possessive-my-mine-your-yours-etc)